# Ubuntu 12.04: updating package message

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dpkg

When ever I updated packages, (they update) I receive the following message about TeXLive:

```
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 2888 package 'texlive-local':
 missing maintainer
```

This doesn't mess up the packages downloading or upgrading.  I would like to have this stop though.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've never heard of a package called `texlive-local`. Where does it come from? Is this a locally built package?

Comment: @FaheemMitha probably a PPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `texlive-local` is malformed. The [`Maintainer` field](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-maintainer) in packages is mandatory, even though it is not used for any technical reason — it's more of a social requirement to give some tracability to all packages. The lack of this field does not cause any problem, but it's something that shouldn't happen, so `dpkg` is warning you. All official packages do have that field.

The warning message would go away if you removed the `texlive-local` package or if you upgraded to a version with a `Maintainer` field. I recommend that you recommend to the maintainer of that package to add a `Maintainer` field with their email address. It goes into `debian/control` in the source tree.

In the meantime, you can get rid of the warning by editing the package database and adding that field manually. Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, search for a line containing exactly `Package: texlive-local`, and add a line containing `Maintainer: someone@example.com` just below (the address should be syntactically well-formed, but it doesn't have to be valid if you would prefer not to put somebody's name in there).

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you! You have backups! And even more, they are made daily without you knowing! So, to restore the files just run:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

Done!

If you need even older files there are more from where to pick:

```
ls /var/backups/dpkg.status*
/var/backups/dpkg.status.0     /var/backups/dpkg.status.4.gz
/var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz  /var/backups/dpkg.status.5.gz
/var/backups/dpkg.status.2.gz  /var/backups/dpkg.status.6.gz
/var/backups/dpkg.status.3.gz
```

Just uncompress them using `gunzip`:

```
gunzip -c /var/backups/dpkg.status.6.gz > /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My own post in AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/343620/169736

**If the backups are no good**, another way is doing a list of the `doc` directory contents:

```
sudo -i
ls /usr/share/doc | \
      grep -v [A-Z] | \
      grep -v '^texmf$' | \
      grep -v '^debian$' | \
      awk '{print $1 " install"}' | \
      dpkg --set-selections
```

http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/debianproblem.htm

Comment: I just added a maintainer after size around line 2887 and I think that worked.  I can report back in a few days if it truly worked.

Comment: This was not just today that you saw it, but very old, right? That's why the backups were no good.

Comment: I have seen it for awhile but decided to ask about it.

Comment: That's a bad idea — restoring from a backup only works to undo the last action, and dustin doesn't want to undo the last action.

Comment: @Gilles it is the most popular action all around (googling `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with `missing` `corrupted` `parsing` recommends using the backups) for fixing this message and I added another one to nuke the status which as you see, do not use a backup.

Comment: @Gilles also, he wants to stop the message from appearing, I don't see where my solution wouldn't do that. Is destructive? Yeah. There is another way? Yeah, editing manually the files. What is most secure? There is the problem.